# Passing functions as parameters in classes C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Next answers not responding my question:
C++ How to pass member function pointer to another class? (2 answers)
How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected? (9 answers)
Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer (10 answers)

I have two classes:

```
typedef void (*pPrintContent)(QPainter& painter, bool friendly);

class KonsolePrintManager : QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit KonsolePrintManager(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent){}
    void printRequest(pPrintContent pContent, QWidget *parent);
```

And:

```
class TerminalDisplay : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void printContent(QPainter &painter, bool friendly);
    void printScreen();
```

In printScreen () I intend to do something like:

```
void TerminalDisplay::printScreen()
{
    KonsolePrintManager pManager(this);
    pManager.printRequest(printContent, this); #Here the error occurs
}
```

And the error occurs when passing the printContent () function as a parameter of printRequest.

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: You forgot to specify "the error" that occurs.

Comment: The error is   invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Konsole::TerminalDisplay::printContent(QPainter&, bool)’
 4138 |     pManager.printRequest(this->printContent, this);